# API development endpoints mapping to server scripts

Tags: api, api-design

I’m new to API development and I have a question that might seem dumb, but I literally have no experience with API design, so bear with me.

Having said that, my question is: should different resources point to different scripts on the server? Or all resources should point to the same script, with different arguments?

E.g.:

`/countries/{country_id}/` should point to `/path_to_api/countries?country_id={country_id}`

and

`/cities/{city_id}/` should point to `/path_to_api/cities?city_id={city_id}`

or

`/path_to_api/api?resource=countries&country_id={country_id}`

and

`/path_to_api/api?resource=cities&city_id={city_id}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you structure your files should have no bearing to the design of your REST API. One of the most common mistake when designing a REST API is having artifacts in the URLs that are due to implementation details like the technology used (e.g. php) rather than because of purely design considerations. Suppose you imagine that you are going to rewrite this application in the future with different technology stack, you should not have to change your API design because of an early design decision to include irrelevant information (.php) in the URL. Even worse is if you have a URL that ends with .php but was actually implemented in Java, or something like that.

Whether you implement

`/countries/{country_id}` pointing to `/path_to_api/countries?id={country_id}`

or

`/countries/{country_id}` pointing to `/path_to_api/api?resource=country&id={country_id}`

both are ok.

Comment: I edited the question and removed the PHP part, in order to make it more generic, as it is not important to what I’m interested in. (Thanks!) So basically it has more to do with each other’s preferences than with one or other technical reasons, right?

Comment: @Alex: I think you missed my point. Whether you have a single resources.php that handles multiple resources, or whether you have a customized countries.php that implements only countries, it doesn't matter from API design perspective. Those are implementation details, you should just do what you think is easiest and most maintainable. In practice, you'll likely have to do both, with simpler resources having a common script that handles simple CRUD API, and more complex resources being customized for that particular resource with resource-specific validation and processing.